What does "to" mean in "a servant to the circumcised" in Romans 15:8?
From Romans 15:8-9 ESV

"For I tell you that Christ became a servant to the circumcised to show  God's truthfulness, in order to confirm the promises given to the patriarchs, 9  and in order that the Gentiles might glorify God for his mercy." [My emphasis].

Various translations use either "to" or "of",
e.g.,
ESV "to the circumcised".
NLB "to the Jews".
NIV "of the circumcised".
Berean S.B. "of the Jews".
Do "to" and "of" here have the same meaning?
Does the Greek here support the use of either "to" or "of"?
Are "to" and "of" equally valid translations of "peritomes"?

περιτομῆς (undisputed) is the genitive feminine singular, not the dative. See Biblehub.

Strictly speaking the word περιτομῆς (peritomēs) in Rom 15:8 is in the genitive case which means it must be translated as either:

"of circumcision" which would give, "* ... Christ has become a servant of circumcision ...*"
"circumcision's" which would give, "* ... Christ has become circumcision's servant ...*"

Notice that there is no article before "circumcision" in the Greek.
Now, neither of the above actually conveys the meaning and force of the Greek as it is not discussing circumcision as a practice but the group of circumcised people.  Therefore, most modern translations, in order to convey this do one or more of several things:

provide an article before "circumcision" to show that the Greek is discussing a group of people
change the noun "circumcision" to an adjective, "circumcised", again to show (in English) what the noun is doing in Greek - discussing a group of people and NOT a procedure.
change the preposition to "to" - a practice that is often demanded of the Greek because the Greek sometimes uses the genitive for the dative especially when distinction is required from previous datives to prevent confusion with a possible apposition as in this verse.

However, to minimize the alteration to the text, I would translate this text as:

For I say: Christ has become a servant of [the] circumcised on behalf of
[the] truth of God ...

